# IOS Swift get selected image path

Tags: ios, swift, image, path

Kindly let me know the way to get the path of the image selected using the picker view.

```
    func addImage(sender: AnyObject){

    picController.allowsEditing = false
    picController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary
    self.presentViewController(picController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage, editingInfo: [String : AnyObject]?) {
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    titleImageView.image = image
   //Get the path of the image selected
   // print(path)
}
```

I would like to print the path of the image. 
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Working code

```
    func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController!, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage!, editingInfo: NSDictionary!){
    self.titleImageView.image = image
    let url: NSURL = editingInfo.valueForKey("UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL") as! NSURL
    print(url.absoluteString)
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: hi I am getting this error **Creating an image format with an unknown type is an error
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value** help me to solve this

Answer (score 0):

The `UIImagePickerController` API you're using provides a reference to a UIImage object via delegation. With this UIImage reference you can write the image to file and use that path. In order to obtain a reference to the image asset in the library, you'll need to use a different delegate callback: `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo`. Simply obtain the path from the info dictionary's `UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL`.

For more information, see Apple's [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate/imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:).

Comment: thank you @Stavash, i tried the below code but im getting error 
**fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value**

       ` func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController!, didFinishPickingImage image: UIImage!, editingInfo: NSDictionary!){
        
        
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: { () -> Void in
            let url   = editingInfo.valueForKeyPath("UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL") as! NSURL
            
            print(url.path)
            self.titleImageView.image = image
        })
        
    }`